# "echo checking" in expect script

Tags: expect, forth

I'm writing an expect script to upload Forth source files to a microcontroller over /dev/ttyUSB0.

My aim is to color the "ok" prompt green, "Redefine" yellow and exit on an error such as "not found".

The problem I am having is with the characters being sent too fast. I know that I could use a delay like so:

```
set send_slow {1 .1}
```

But this is not optimal. Is there an option to check that a character has been echoed back while allowing for some extra feedback like the ok prompt? Here's the start of my script:

```
set dev [lindex $argv 0]
set portId [open $dev RDWR]
spawn -open $portId -noecho

set send_slow {1 .1}

for {set i 1} {$i < $argc} {incr i 1} {
    set filename [lindex $argv $i]
        set fd [open $filename r]
        set forth_src [read $fd]
        puts "Uploading $filename"

        set lines [split $forth_src "\n"]
        send -s "\r\n\r\n"
        set lines [split $forth_src "\n"]
        foreach line $lines {
            send -s $line
            send -s "\r\n"
                expect {
                    "ok." { }
                    "not found." { exit }
                    timeout { exit }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have u tried increasing the `send_slow` value ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of a delay so that I never have to send slower than I need to.

Comment: `foreach filename $argv` is more compact